# ShapeLayer HitTest on path not working for me

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a quick question for you guys.

I have a shapeLayer in which I set a frame.
Then I draw a shape inside the frame content with UIBezierPath which i set to the shapeLayer.path

The question is, how do i detect tap inside the shape as true and outside the shape as false ?

I have been trying all kind of crazy stuff but none are working

```
-(Boolean) isPoint:(CGPoint)point InsideShape:(CSAbstractShapeLayer*) shapeLayer fromSuperLayer:(CALayer*) sLayer
{ 
    CGPoint locationPoint   = point;
    locationPoint           = [sLayer convertPoint:locationPoint toLayer:shapeLayer];        
    CGAffineTransform at    = shapeLayer.affineTransform;            
    return CGPathContainsPoint([shapeLayer path],&at, locationPoint, NO);       
}


-(Boolean) isPoint:(CGPoint)point InsideShape:(CSAbstractShapeLayer*) shapeLayer fromSuperLayer:(CALayer*) sLayer
{ 
    CGPoint locationPoint   = point;        
    locationPoint           = [sLayer convertPoint:locationPoint toLayer:shapeLayer];        
    return [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:shapeLayer.path] containsPoint:locationPoint];    
}


-(Boolean) isPoint:(CGPoint)point InsideShape:(CSAbstractShapeLayer*) shapeLayer fromSuperLayer:(CALayer*) sLayer
{ 
    CGPoint locationPoint   = point;        
    locationPoint           = [sLayer convertPoint:locationPoint toLayer:shapeLayer];        
    CGRect theRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(theRect, locationPoint);    
}
```

NOTE 1: It seems that I can't post an image yet so picture a rectangle with diagonal line inside, the
right side of the line is the shape so I need to detect tap inside as YES and outside (left of line and outside of rectangle) as NO

NOTE 2: May be that could help but I can't make sense of it....I have discovered that if you create a shapeLayer and add a CGPath to the shapeLayer.path and do not provide a frame, the frame and the bound of the shapeLayer is [0,0,0,0] even though the shape is rendered on screen therefore, [view.layer hitTest:point] won't find the shapeLayer as a target. because of this, I have provided a frame and a bound to my shapeLayer.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short,

At the layer level,  I was using the point I got from the View (locationInView) and then do a conversion to the layer but this layer had a parent layer therefore I needed to do two conversions

So if look at that method  I sent you the other day

```
-(Boolean) isPoint:(CGPoint)point InsideShape:(CSAbstractShapeLayer*) shapeLayer fromSuperLayer:(CALayer*) sLayer
{

 
    CGPoint locationPoint   = point;

        
    locationPoint           = [sLayer convertPoint:locationPoint toLayer:shapeLayer];       

 
    return [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:shapeLayer.path] containsPoint:locationPoint];    

}
```

I had to do the following

1. `locationPoint = [ sLayer.superlayer convertPoint: locationPoint toLayer: sLayer];`
2. `locationPoint = [ sLayer convertPoint: locationPoint toLayer: shapeLayer];`

So from the parentLayer superLayer to itself then from it to the childLayer

Hope that help someone